# java.sql.sqlexception parameter index out of range (1 number of parameters which is 0) can't run it

Tags: java, sql

What do I gonna do?
I can't run it 
error comes up like this

> java.sql.sqlexception parameter index out of range (1 number of parameters which is 0)

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webservice","root","");

    String url ="Insert into employeeid(Fullname,EmployeeID,Username,Password,Address,Cell Phone,City,Zip,Home Phone,Position,Emergency Contact,Emergency Phone,License #) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    pst=conn.prepareStatement(url);
    pst.setString(1, txt_name.getText());
    pst.setString(2, txt_id.getText());
    pst.setString(3, txt_user.getText());
    pst.setString(4, txt_pass.getText());
    pst.setString(5, txt_add.getText());
    pst.setString(6, txt_cp.getText());
    pst.setString(7, txt_city.getText());
    pst.setString(8, txt_zip.getText());
    pst.setString(9, txt_homep.getText());
    pst.setString(10, txt_pos.getText());
    pst.setString(11, txt_econ.getText());
    pst.setString(12, txt_ephone.getText());
    pst.setString(13, txt_lic.getText());

    pst.executeUpdate(url);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved");  
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
Update_table();
// TODO add your handling code here:
```

Comment: You want to call `pst.executeUpdate()` (without parameter).

Comment: it wont work..
but thanks ^^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would try:

1. change. 'GetText' values ​​by

   ```
   pst.setString (1 txt_name.getText ()); 
   to 
   pst.setString (1, "Luis");
   ```
2. If this works the problem occurs in class txt

try running your IDE debug

If you can not identify the problem even with debug, I can help you more if I spend the rest of the code + database creation script

Answer (score 1):

I doubt about

```
String url ="Insert into employeeid(Fullname,EmployeeID,Username,Password,Address,Cell Phone,City,Zip,Home Phone,Position,Emergency Contact,Emergency Phone,License #) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                                 (^) Here this table name                                                                                                          (^)This #
```

**Also check the number of column in db for this particular table**

Suggesstion `pst.setString(2, txt_id.getText());` this kinda is not recommended you can use `integer`, `long` type for id specification

Comment: yeah it works..
hahaha
Thanks dude..
Youre the Man!! xD